# aes_cbc_encrypt() not correctly decrypting data

Tags: aes, aes-gcm

My goal is to not use the `EVP` functions from `OpenSSL`. I know this is possible because I basically broke down thousands of lines of C code for the key derivation to a standalone embedded program and it was not easy.

But now I would like to actually encrypt/decrypt data. The two functions are assembly routines found in `/crypto/aes/aesni-x86_64.s`, actually. I'm just a bit burned out from reading more code. I'm looking for the direct functions that just do the encryption using the `AES_256_CBC` cipher or `AES_256_GCM`. I found the `aes_gcm_encrypt` in `crypto/modes/aesni-gcm-x86_64.s`

This code takes the string in `in` and encrypts it to `tmp`, then decrypts it back to `out` but it doesn't actually decrypt correctly. Any ideas? Am I missing other routines before using the actual assembly functions? And if so, can someone just point me to where that is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

int aesni_set_encrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, const int bits, AES_KEY *key);
int aesni_set_decrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, int bits,
                          AES_KEY *key);
void aesni_cbc_encrypt(const unsigned char *in,
                       unsigned char *out,
                       size_t length,
                       const AES_KEY *key, unsigned char *ivec, int enc);

int main()
{
    int i;
    unsigned char key[] = "\xE0\xE6\x0C\x86\xF1\x10\xF5\x3A\x4E\x65\x88\x79\x74\xB1\x4E\x3D\x06\x22\x9D\xB9\x4E\x26\x25\xBE\xD1\x18\x2B\x56\x73\xAB\x44\xF3";
    unsigned char iv[]  = "\x06\x22\x9D\xB9\x4E\x26\x25\xBE\xD1\x18\x2B\x56\x73\xAB\x44\xF3";
    unsigned char in[]  = "\x64\x6f\x20\x77\x68\x61\x74\x63\x68\x61\x20\x68\x61\x66\x74\x61";
    unsigned char out[16];
    unsigned char tmp[16];

    // print plaintext
    size_t blksz = 16;
    for (i=0;i<blksz;i++)
        printf("%02x ", in[i]);
    puts("");

    AES_KEY ks;
    aesni_set_encrypt_key(key, 256, &ks);
    aesni_cbc_encrypt(in, tmp, blksz, &ks, iv, 1); // 1 = encrypt

    // print ciphertext
    for (i=0;i<blksz;i++)
        printf("%02x ", tmp[i]);
    puts("");


    // decrypt

    aesni_set_decrypt_key(key, 256, &ks);
    aesni_cbc_encrypt(tmp, out, blksz, &ks, iv, 0); // 0 = decrypt

    // print decrypted plaintext
    for (i=0;i<blksz;i++)
        printf("%02x ", out[i]);
    puts("");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: **That function updates the IV** (to allow chained operation) so you decrypt with a different=wrong IV giving a wrong result. You need to either reinitialize the IV before decrypting, or use a copy of the IV not the original for your function calls. (PS: the fact the `ivec` parameter is NOT declared pointer-to-const hints at this.)

Comment: I used a copy of the iv and that actually did work. Thanks for pointing out what that function does. Generally, though, how strong is this encryption if I were to just use this directly? Can it be easily cracked? Am I missing out on anything that the EVP function does? For key derivation, I had to manually copy over the MD5_Update and Hash_Update and that included the `ossl_md5_block_asm_data_order`. Once I was able to get the key, I loaded it with the functions I posted so I know they are used with key derivation but I was wondering if these are the actual functions used with `aes_cbc_256` ?

Comment: i just noticed that `tmp` and `iv` are identical after encryption. so basically you need the same iv and the same buffer but original key to get the output.

Comment: In CBC mode the ciphertext is the vector to XOR with the next plaintext before block encryption. Of course this won't work for the first block which is where the IV is used. CBC mode is secure for confidentiality for data at rest. Padding is missing from the functions so the code won't work for plaintext that's not a multiple of the block size.

Comment: Yes, for single-block data the new-IV _is_ the ciphertext; for longer data it would be only the last block of the ciphertext. In addition to handling padding, the EVP functions will call these functions ONLY on x86-family CPUs with AESNI instructions. On other CPUs these functions will either crash or not exist, so EVP uses other code that works. Thus EVP code works everywhere OpenSSL exists, and your code doesn't. Also using MD5 to derive the key means it is slower than AES128 but not stronger.

Comment: i just implemented padding, was a bit of a pain but just tested it and works great. i understand it is designed only for that platform. i can also downgrade to plain aes without ni but the target arch will handle both.